# Frequent background fetch using NSTimerInterval

Tags: ios

I am building an iOS application (using Xamarin, but that's not important) that periodically sends the RSSI of nearby Bluetooth LE devices to my server (if there are any nearby BLE).

I want to do this frequently while the app is in the background, but am concerned that Apple will not allow this. I am planning on using background fetch to do this, specifying `NSTimerInterval` to 10 seconds so my server will be pinged every 10 seconds.

Will this work? Or will Apple reject this approach?

Comment: It's not an SO question, but no, almost certainly not.  Your app doesn't seem to fall in the categories described here beside appearing to a battery killer with privacy implications. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: I was considering using `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` and ping my server every time the user's position changes by 5 meters...and I'll only do this when my (specific) BLE devices are nearby. I think that's a better approach, but still too much of a battery killer?

Comment: I think your bigger problem is being a background app that does something other than what Apple says background apps are supposed to do.

Comment: @Darius Neither of those approaches will work in any event; With background fetch your app will be invoked every hour or so, at most.  With significant location change, you will be notified when the user moves approximately 500m.  You also cannot scan RSSI in the background as the Core Bluetooth scan duplicates key cannot be used in the background.  This app would be neither battery nor network traffic friendly, so it is not suitable for background execution.  You can do what you want in the foreground where the user is aware of the app's operation

Comment: Sorry, not `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, I meant to say to monitor every 5 meters (I know there's a way...). But I get your point. Thanks.

Comment: "Best" navigation can give you updates every 5/10m, but only outside.  Indoor GPS coverage typically isn't good enough for precise location updates, but unless your app has a clear need for precise background location you may be rejected.  It will also kill the battery. But your biggest issue is simply scanning for BLE peripherals in the background is basically limited to scanning for a known service and you cannot get multiple updates, only a single notification when a new peripheral is discovered.

Comment: I actually know the service UUID that I'm scanning for, but yeah I would need to know its RSSI every ~5/10 seconds/meters. Is there any documentation that indicates this? The one on developer.apple.com doesn't have any details on this.

Comment: Apparently this project can broadcast UUID and read RSSI while in the background: https://github.com/Instrument/Vicinity

Comment: I thought of an idea: what if my peripheral updates a characteristic every 5 seconds? That way, my app's delegate will be called and I can `readRSSI()` from there!